# Place media attachment in other directory (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress

My client is using an old media attachment URL for their email signature logotype. This image has now been removed and I would like to upload the same image again and place it in the same directory as before, recreating the URL.

However, when I upload a new media file to Wordpress, the file automatically is placed in a directory that corresponds with the current date: `.../wp-content/uploads/2018/09`. I would like to place it in the directories `.../wp-content/uploads/2015/09/`.

Is it safe to manually create these folders and upload the file via FTP or would the manually added files be overwritten or removed in some way upon updating Wordpress? If so, is there some other way to change the date of a media attachment and automatically create the correct folders depending on the date I change it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there isn't a folder "2015" in your /wp-content/uploads you can add this folder through your FTP program, same goes for the monthly folder. If the folder for the year and/or month are already there you can just upload the image to the desired folder by using your FTP program.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up doing exactly that. Considering it's not necessary that Wordpress knows about the image (if I for example were to migrate the media library) and as long as WP doesn't delete the file when I update, this seemed like the most simple solution.